# Auto-width for a Blogpost Title?

Tags: css

I want to make the title box auto-width, but I don't get it. Cannot post any Screenshots. My Css Code for the blogpost title is actually like this:

```
section#maincontent header{
position: relative;
left: 25px;
padding-left: 10px;
background: #e5e5e5;
margin-top: 50px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;

-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
border-top-right-radius: 15px;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

Need help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you post your HTML code we'd probably be able to help you better, but in general a `div` is a block level element, so it will automatically expand to the width of its containing element. If you want the title to appear in a box that is as wide as the title itself (with a little padding) consider changing the div to `display:inline`, styling the title itself, or wrap it in an inline-element such as a `span`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DHW7Y/7/

Comment: "If you want the title to appear in a box that is as wide as the title itself (with a little padding)" that's exactly what I wanted to do. The code above is the code for the headline title (have a look onto the homepage).

Comment: @Stef check out the JSFiddle and let me know if it does what you need.

Comment: Hey Rollin Stone, thank you for helping me. display: inline; doesn't help, have a look at what it does: http://www.stefano-lucka.de

Comment: hmmm...trying wrapping your title in `<h1>` tags instead. i updated the jsfiddle above with an example that you can see.

Comment: i think the fail is at another place i haven't seen yet.. because the title box is as wide as the blogpost is.. thanks for your help, got to go for the present